# Definition of Harmonic funcitons on the Riemann Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently reading *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* by Thomas Ransford. In the first chapter he specifies harmonicity at infinity as follows:

> Given a funciton $h$ defined on an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\infty$, we say $h$ is harmonic on $U$ if $h\circ \phi^{-1}$ is harmonic on $\phi(U)$, where $\phi$ is a conformal mapping of $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I'm a bit confused as to what this means. Does conformal in this sense for instance allow that $\phi^{-1}(z_0) = \infty$ for some point $z_0\in U$? Would this not then imply that $1/z$ is a conformal map of the Riemann sphere even though it is not differentiable at the origin albeit continuous as a map of the Riemann sphere into itself?

Is there some kind of general definition of a conformal map on the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Is $\phi$ defined to be $\phi(z)=1/z$ in the first place?

Comment: No I was just thinking if it was then an example of what is considered a conformal map of the Riemann sphere

Comment: $\phi$ is in this case an arbitrary conformal map from an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to the Riemann sphere mapping onto $\infty$

Comment: Do you know about Riemann surfaces? The Riemann sphere is a Riemann surface, on which you can strictly define what is meant by a conformal map. Although, given that the sphere is a very specific example, there might be a simplified definition of conformal maps consistent with those on a Riemann surface (in which case $z\to\frac{1}{z}$ is indeed conformal). I am surprised the author did not clarify this in previous sections.

Comment: Ok I didn't know this about the definition of conformal maps on Riemann surfaces

Comment: Check any book on Riemann surfaces. The Riemann sphere and conformal maps should come right after the definition of Riemann surfaces.